# ajax para actualizar dataTable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Envió los datos, la respuesta en la consola tiene los datos correctos , pero no se me actualiza el dataTable con esos nuevos datos que me devolvió la respuesta, ojala me puedan ayudar, ya no se como mas hacer pruebas.

```js
//Script que esta en el index.php
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 listar();
});
var listar = function(){ 
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({

     "ajax":{
      "url":"busca.php",
      "type":"POST"
      
     },
     "columns":[
      {"data":"Fecha"},
      {"data":"Hora"},
      {"data":"NumAla"},
      {"data":"Maquina"},
      {"data":"Motivo"},
      {"data":"Comentario"}
     ],
      'pageLength': 40,
      'destroy': true,
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : true,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false,
      "scrollY"     : "200px",
 
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "language"    :{"search":"Buscar", "zeroRecords":"Sin Resultados Coincidentes",
      "paginate": {
        "first":      "Primera",
        "last":       "Ultima",
        "next":       "Siguiente",
        "previous":   "Anterior"
         },
     "info":      "Mostrando _START_ de _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ Registros",
      },

      });
};
    $('#busca').on('submit',function(e){
     var dato1 = $('#fechaid').val();
     var dato2 = $('#folio').val();
        alert(dato1+dato2);
        e.preventDefault();
        var datos1 = $('#busca').serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
         url:"busca.php",
         type:"POST",
         
         data:datos1,
         success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);

    }

        });



        $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();

        
    })


</script>
```

```html
ESTE ES EL busca.php
<?php 
include ("funciones/bd_conec.php");

//$fecha = $_POST['fechaid'];
//$folio = $_POST['folio'];

    //echo '<pre>';
    //var_dump($_POST);
    //echo '</pre>';


if ($_POST['pas']==1) {

    $fecha = $_POST['fechaid'];
    $folio = $_POST['folio'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE NumAla NOT LIKE '0' and Fecha = '$fecha'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if( !$resultado ){
        die("Error");
    }else{
        while ( $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $arreglo["data"][] = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
    }

    echo json_encode($arreglo);



} 
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE NumAla NOT LIKE '0' and Fecha = '04-02-2019'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if( !$resultado ){
    die("Error");
}else{
    while ( $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $arreglo["data"][] = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
    }

    echo json_encode($arreglo);


}
}


//mysqli_free_result($resultado);
//mysqly_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: No logro solucionar el problema :(

Answer (score 0):

Hola @jonathan creo que el problema se debe a que deberías llamar la función reload desde la variable asignada a la tabla, en tu caso seria:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({..}); //estructura de la tabla

table.ajax.reload(); //acción para se lean nuevamente los datos de la tabla
```

Ahora bien, si quieres llamar la tabla cada vez que se ejecute el evento click, yo haría algo así:

```
var table;
var jsonResult = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    llamarDatos("");    
});

$('#busca').on('submit', function (e) {
    var dato1 = $('#fechaid').val();
    var dato2 = $('#folio').val();
    alert(dato1 + dato2);
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos1 = $('#busca').serializeArray();
    llamarDatos(datos1);
    //$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();    
});

function llamarDatos(datos){
    $.ajax({
        url: "busca.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datos,
        success: function (data) {
            jsonResult = data;
        },
        complete: function(){
            CargarTabla();
        }
    });
}

function CargarTabla(){
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "aaData": jsonResult,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Fecha" },
            { "data": "Hora" },
            { "data": "NumAla" },
            { "data": "Maquina" },
            { "data": "Motivo" },
            { "data": "Comentario" }
        ],
        'pageLength': 10,
        'paging': true,
        'lengthChange': false,
        'searching': true,
        'ordering': true,
        'info': true,
        'autoWidth': false,
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "language": {
            "search": "Buscar", "zeroRecords": "Sin Resultados Coincidentes",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Primera",
                "last": "Ultima",
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            },
            "info": "Mostrando _START_ de _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ Registros",
        },

    });
}
```

Pasando a una variable global los datos que devuelve el Ajax y con la propiedad bDestroy de DataTable se generaría una nueva lectura de los datos al realizar un cambio.

Comment: No funciona....señalo que ademas table is not define.

Comment: Recuerda inicializar las variables fuera de las funciones para poder acceder a ellas desde otras funciones?

Comment: Perdon, pero no lo logro resolver....

Answer (score 0):

Mi propuesta es la siguiente, trataré de explicar lo mejor posible, se basa en una sola url como origen de los datos del datatables tanto para su carga inicial como para la posible búsqueda a realizar a través del submit del formulario #busca.
En lo particular las funcionalidades que tratan datos reflejados en un datatable las manejo desde el evento init del propio datatables, pero como tal no es que sea nada obligado; entonces:

```
$(function () {
    var _tablaElement = $('#example');
    var _dtAPI = $(_tablaElement)
            .on('draw.dt', function () {
                /** 
                 *  este es un ejemplo de lo que puedes hacer cada vez que se dibuje
                 *  una página del datables, en este caso lo que se hace es reducir el padding de las celdas
                 **/
                $(_tablaElement).find('tbody tr td').css('padding', '5px 5px 5px 5px');
            })
            .on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
                /*
                 * Agregamos los datos serializados del formulario #busca, que imagino inicialmente estan en blanco
                 * garantizando que desde el lado del servidor siempre se reciban los mismos parametros.
                 **/
                
                data.fechaVal = $('#fechaid').val();
                data.folioVal = $('#folio').val();

                // a manera de ejemplo: no deseamos filtrar por columnas por tanto eliminamos de la peticion estas variables.
                data.columns = [];
            })
            .on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json, xhr) {
                /**
                 * A manera de ejemplo en este evento del espacio de datatables podemos manipular la respuesta dada por el servidor
                 * digamos para los codigos de estado de error, 0: error de red, 401 sesion necesita autienticacion, 400-500 otros tipos de errores
                 **/

                switch (xhr.status) {
                    case 0:
                        toastr.error("Conexión interrumpida!!!", '', {
                            timeOut: 2100,
                            preventDuplicates: false,
                            positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                            progressBar: true,
                            showDuration: 800,
                            hideDuration: 400,
                            extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                            showEasing: "swing",
                            hideEasing: "linear",
                            showMethod: "fadeIn",
                            hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                        });
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", '', {
                            timeOut: 2400,
                            preventDuplicates: false,
                            positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                            onHidden: function () {
                                window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 400:
                    case 403:
                    case 404:
                    case 406:
                    case 500:
                        toastr.error(xhr.responseText, '', {
                            timeOut: 2500,
                            preventDuplicates: false,
                            positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                            progressBar: true,
                            showDuration: 800,
                            hideDuration: 400,
                            extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                            showEasing: "swing",
                            hideEasing: "linear",
                            showMethod: "fadeIn",
                            hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            })
            .on('init.dt', function () {
                /**
                 * Una vez inicializados el datatables (este evento se dispara una sola vez al recargar la pagina).
                 *
                 * Aqui es donde enlazaremos el buscar del formulario con el refrescar (actualizar) del datatables.
                 **/
                $('#busca').on('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    _dtAPI.ajax.fechaVal = $('#fechaid').val();
                    _dtAPI.ajax.folioVal = $('#folio').val();
                    
                    // al hacer submit al form, se recarga el datatables sin mantener la paginacion en este caso
                    _dtAPI.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    
                });

            })
            .DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "busca.php",
                    "type": "POST"

                },
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "Fecha"},
                    {"data": "Hora"},
                    {"data": "NumAla"},
                    {"data": "Maquina"},
                    {"data": "Motivo"},
                    {"data": "Comentario"}
                ],
                // demas propiedades del datatables
            });
});
```

De esa manera garantizarás que a tu controlador siempre le lleguen las mismas variables en la peticion tanto para inicializar el datatables como para realizar la busqueda; tendrás siempre por POST:

```
$draw=$_POST['draw'];
$start=$_POST['start'];
$length=$_POST['length'];
$search=$_POST['search'];

// y además tendrás vacíos o con valor:
$fechaVal=$_POST['fechaVal'];
$folioVal=$_POST['folioVal'];
```

Así que tu función en el controlador está lista para procesar tanto una inicialización del datatables, como una posible búsqueda filtrando por fecha y folio.
**OJO** *no me detengo en formular la query a la base de datos totalmente, el siguiente código es solo para que tengas una idea, se entiende que debes usar mysqli para formular tus queries parametrizadas y evitar inyección SQL.*

```
$registrosPrincipalQuery= "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE (1=1)";
$totalRegistrosQuery="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Datos";

$contadorRegistrosFiltradosQuery="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Datos WHERE (1=1)";
if(empty($fechaVal) === false){
   $registrosPrincipalQuery.= "  AND (Datos.fecha = $fechaVal)";
   $contadorRegistrosFiltradosQuery.= " AND (Datos.fecha = $fechaVal)";
}

if(empty($folioVal) === false){
   $registrosPrincipalQuery.= "  AND (Datos.folio = $folioVal)";
   $contadorRegistrosFiltradosQuery.= " AND (Datos.folio = $folioVal)";
}
```

Aplicar limite y offset a la consulta principal y al contador de registros filtrados (esta es la que garantiza te de la cantidad de resultados por paginas deseados).

```
$registrosPrincipalQuery.= " LIMIT $length OFFSET $start";
$contadorRegistrosFiltradosQuery.= " LIMIT $length OFFSET $start";
```

Ejecultar las 3 consultas anteriores, y sobre la consulta principal debes iterar para tener las filas correspondientes a la pagina del datatables.

La respuesta json que expecta el datatables de este controlador será un array con el siguiente formato:

$dataRespuesta = [
'draw' => (int) $draw,
'recordsTotal' => (int) $totalRegistrosQueryResult,
'recordsFiltered' => (int) $contadorRegistrosFiltradosQueryResult,
'data' => $data // contiene un arreglo con los registros de acuerdo a la definición de las columnas que hiciste en tu datatables.
];

hacer `json_encode($dataRespuesta)`